# How try call (recconnect) Json?

Tags: java, json, android-studio

```js
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewItemList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Connect...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        jsoncall();
    }

    public void jsoncall() {
        ArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_JSON, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                String temp;

                pDialog.dismiss();

                Loading_items.Load_list(NewItemList.this,response.length());

                for (int i = 0 ; i<response.length();i++) {
                    try {

                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        BaseItems items_info = new BaseItems();

                        items_info.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                      
                        CheckList.add(items_info);
                        Loading_items.AddItemOne();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setRvadapter(CheckList);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NewItemList.this);
        requestQueue.add(ArrayRequest);
    }
```

If the Internet stable - json works = everything well;
If to start without the Internet - pDialog isn't switched off = everything well;
If to start without the Internet, to cause jsoncall (); and to include the Internet - onResponse isn't carried out and I don't receive json = BAD :(;
How can I try to reconnect json? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnuB7.png)

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please be a bit more clear what you are trying to do? Do you want to reload a Json file? Or simply add another kind of error handling in case you have no or a bad internet connection?

Comment: hi)) I want to make so: If the device without the Internet has started the jsoncall() and then the device has included the Internet; that the program will try to cause again the jsoncall() to finish work; p.s. For example now if the user was in the metro, without the Internet, has caused the jsoncall(), there was a pDialog window, he went out of the metro and there was an Internet, then the program doesn't work correctly and jsoncall isn't carried out up to the end.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note that when commenting back to someone such as @quant, pre-pend their name in your comment with a `@` symbol to notify them of your comment. Also to help improve your question and increase your chances of getting a decent answer, please [edit] your question, including the information above in it, including pertinent code as code-formatted text, not as an image. No one can copy, paste, compile and run an image, and so fixing problems with code presented this way is very difficult.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually one can compile an image ... May I present piet: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html

Comment: @quant magic x))

Comment: @quant: well I'll be darned. I try to learn something new every day, and so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved so: 
1) I have created a class of check of the Internet
2) I cause jsoncall () here so:

```js
  Thread myThready = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            while (!TryConnectionInternet.TryConnectionInternet(NewItemList.this)){}
            jsoncall();
        }
    });
        myThready.start();
```